# Check if xml element of array has exact values with Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

can you tell me how to check if my xml contains nested element in array with exact values? Here is my sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
      <identifier>100</identifier>
      <value>ABC</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <identifier>200</identifier>
      <value>XYZ</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <identifier>100</identifier>
      <value>DEF</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <identifier>300</identifier>
      <value>GFH</value>
   </item>
</items>
```

For instance, I need check if xml above contains element with `identifier = 100` and element with this identifier must has `value = DEF`. It could be on any index in array items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath expression

```xml
"//item[./identifier='100'][./value='DEF']"
```

Or this

```xml
"//item[./identifier='100' and ./value='DEF']"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that these expressions actually do what Denis wants, to be honest. This will return the `items` root element if it contains any `item` which contains an `identifier` equal to `100` and _also_ contains an `item` which contains a `value` equal to `DEF`, even if those are two different `item` elements. I _think_ Denis wants to check that there's _one_ `item` which has both the desired `identifier` and `value` elements.

Comment: @ConalTuohy maybe. Denis did not clarify that point.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It will not check for an existing item that has identifier 100 AND value DEF, instead it will check that there is an item that has the identifier 100 and there is also a possibly other item that has the value DEF. So the test will pass even you _remove_ the identifier node of the 3rd item completely. Please revisit your answer to be correct. To verify that the xml contains nested element in array with exact values, the query _must be exactly_ like this: `boolean(/items/item[./identifier='100' and ./value='DEF'])`

Comment: I see, thanks @MJG! I have edited my answer. It should be `item` there, not `items` as I wrote by a mistake.

Comment: Thanks @Perolet for fixing, now it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with XPath could be written like this:

```
boolean(/items/item[./identifier='100' and ./value='DEF'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is possibly a little unclear (other answers have interpreted it differently), but I take it to mean that you want an XPath expression that returns `true` if the XML contains at least one `item` element which has *both* a child `identifier` element whose value is `100` and *also* a child `value` element whose value is `DEF`.

Here's a short XPath expression which does that:

```xml
boolean(//item[identifier='100'][value='DEF'])
```

Explanation:

- The `//item` expression is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::item`, and its result is the set of all `item` elements in the document.
- The `[identifier='100']` predicate is a filter which reduces that set of `item` elements to only those for which the expression `identifier='100'` is true; i.e. only those `item` elements which have an `identifier` child element whose string value is `"100"`.
- The `[value='DEF']` predicate is a filter which further reduces that set of `item` elements to only those for which the expression `value='DEF'` is true; i.e. only those `item` elements which have an `value` child element whose string value is `"DEF"`.

Finally, this set of `item` elements is converted to a boolean value by the `boolean()` function; if the set is empty the function returns `false`; if it contains one or more items then the value is `true`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler2P I've taken that on board. I'd just added the answer quickly as I was on my way to bed.